# max function returns unexpected value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In my CakePHP application I wrote a simple Helper to retrieve the last ( = maximum) value of a column, and return the next one:

```
namespace App\Utility;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class CountHelper
{
    static public function GetNextNumber($table_name, $field_name) {
        $q = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get($table_name)->find('all');
        $v = $q->select(['last_value' => $q->func()->max($field_name)])->first()['last_value'];
        if ($v == null) $v = 0;
        return ++$v;
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
$next_num = CountHelper::GetNextNumber('proformas', 'proforma_number');
```

Here a (real) sample table:

```
id  customer_id proforma_number proforma_date   payment_date    proforma_state_id
1   5           1               2020-01-31      2020-02-29      2
2   4           2               2020-01-31      2020-02-28      2
4   2           4               2020-01-31      2020-03-31      2
5   6           5               2020-02-29      2020-03-31      2
6   1           6               2020-02-29      2020-03-31      2
7   2           7               2020-02-29      2020-04-30      3
8   1           8               2020-02-29      2020-03-31      2
9   7           9               2020-03-16      2020-03-31      2
11  1           10              2020-03-31      2020-04-30      2
12  1           11              2020-03-31      2020-04-30      2
13  3           12              2020-03-31      2020-04-30      2
14  2           13              2020-03-31      2020-05-31      1
15  8           14              2020-04-20      2020-05-31      1
17  1           15              2020-04-23      2020-05-31      1
18  2           16              2020-04-30      2020-06-30      1
19  9           17              2020-05-18      2020-05-31      1
```

Debugging the function, `$v` assumes the value 9. And thus the function returns 10. Instead I'm expecting `$v` is equal to 17.

Comment: What column type is `proforma_number`?

Comment: @ndm, good shot. I was *sure* it was an `int`. Instead, for a reason I don't know, it was declared as `varchar`. Changing it to `int` fixed the problem.